# C# Time Stamp Issue

Tags: c#, logging, time

I am writing program events to a txt file as a log but the time stamps are not updating at each point. I have declared the following string:

```
string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ff");
string taskComplete = (timeStamp) + " Task Complete";
```

which i am calling at different points through the program:

```
using (StreamWriter w_Log = new StreamWriter(file_Log, true))
            {
                w_Log.WriteLine(taskComplete);
                w_Log.Close();
            }
```

There are several more strings declared using `timeStamp` though the program as well. Here is an example of the log file:

```
2014/02/22 10:07:26.71 Process started
2014/02/22 10:07:26.71 Task Complete
2014/02/22 10:07:26.71 Task Complete
2014/02/22 10:07:26.71 Process complete, time elapsed: 0.496 seconds
```

As you can see, the time seems to be static even though it has taken 49ms to complete. When the program is run again, the time has changed to the current time but the same issue, the time written is the same throughout.

Do I need to use a different method or am I using this one incorrectly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, at step 1 you're defining a string as being `DateTime.Now` with a particular format

At each point, you're just showing the same string. The string is fixed, it's not going to invoke `DateTime.Now` each time you run it.

So if you want it to change - you're going to need to call `DateTime.Now` each time.

```
w_Log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ff") + " Task Complete ");
```

Comment: Is there a way to set it as a function which can be called as it is used several times throughout the program?

Comment: Sure, there's an answer by psubsee2003 which creates a function 'wrapper' around it. There's no built in function though as far as I know.

Comment: Used it each time now. Code is now littered with these all over now so will look into the answer by psubsee2003 for wrapping it to see if it will tidy up the code a little.

Answer (score 3):

You are defining `taskComplete` as a string once and using it over and over again.  It doesn't update regardless of how you define it.  You could set it once now and leave your the method running for 10 years and it will still contain the same value.

You actually need to update the timestamp value each time you want to update it.  If you were trying to limit the code in this method, you could do is change `taskComplete` to a method that returns a string with the updated timestamp

```
void SomeMethod()
{   
    //doing other stuff 
    using (StreamWriter w_Log = new StreamWriter(file_Log, true))
    {
        w_Log.WriteLine(GetTaskCompleteMessage());
        w_Log.Close();
    }
    //doing other stuff
}

String GetTaskCompleteMessage()
{
    string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ff");
    return = (timeStamp) + " Task Complete";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you  should  redefine your string each time  you want to  update  your  log as you are doing now  the  variable `timeStamp`   was fixed during the lifetime of your  class's instance

```
string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ff");
string taskComplete = (timeStamp) + " Task Complete";
```

//here when you call the log method

```
using (StreamWriter w_Log = new StreamWriter(file_Log, true))
            {

                 timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ff");
                  taskComplete = (timeStamp) + " Task Complete";
                w_Log.WriteLine(taskComplete);
                w_Log.Close();
            }
```